# Why is throughput speed determined by the end system with the slower throughput?

Tags: file-transfer, throughput

I have been researching throughput speed of packet transfers and have been confused about the total throughput from one end system to another. For example: say a server is sending a packet to a client with a router in between. My textbook *Computer Networking* by Kurose and Ross says that the end system with the slower throughput speed determines the throughput speed of the entire file transfer. Why is this?

Wouldn't the two throughput speeds be added together to make up the entire file transfer throughput? For example: the throughput of the server pumps bits out at 1 Mbps and the router pumps bits out at 2 Mbps. Say also that the file size was 10 Million bits. From the server to the router it would take 10 seconds to reach the server and then it would take about 5 seconds to reach the client making the total throughput interaction to take 15 seconds. That's what I would think but using the textbook's logic this would take 10 seconds. Why is this?

Comment: In terms of throughput, think of data like water in a pipe. the diameter of the pipe is the total bandwidth. The volume of water that can pass through that diameter for an arbitrary distance in an arbitrary time is its throughput. a given molecule of water entering the pipe moves through that pipe at a predefined rate, and then enters a subsequent pipe, passing through it at that pipes rate. Since the molecule has  to traverse the entire pipe before entering the subsequent one, the time to traverse both pipes is pipe1Time + pipe2Time. The higher that time is, the lower the rate of speed.

Comment: cont. the lower the rate of speed, the lower the overall throughput rate. So a path can never take less time than the throughput rate of its individual pipes. If one pipe is slower than the others, it doesn't matter how much faster the other pipes are, you are always going to be bottlenecked by the slow pipe and communication along that path will never ever be faster than the slowest pipe's rate. So, to sum up, with Time taken you would all everything together, but for Throughput, you take the rate of the slowest component on the path; you can never go faster than it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a line of ants moving from a Leaf to their hole, but there is a stick in the way they need to climb over:

```
<Leaf> ------ <stick> ------ <hole>
```

It takes 3 seconds for an ant to reach the stick (leg1 of the journey), 10 seconds to climb over the stick (leg2), and then 2 seconds to move from the stick to the hole (Leg3). The total bandwidth of leg1 is 3 ants, the bandwidth of the stick is one ant, and the bandwidth of leg3 is 3 ants.

So ant0 leaves the leaf, and travels to the stick. he climbs over the stick, and walks to the hole. Total time = 15 seconds.

Ant1 leaves 1 second behind ant0, and traverses leg1 in three seconds. It gets to the stick, but the sticks bandwidth is full because Ant0 is using it. so Ant1 has to wait 9 seconds before it can BEGIN crossing the stick. When Ant0 is done on the stick, Ant1 crosses it and continues onto the hole. Total time taken is 3s + 9s (waiting) + 10s crossing the stick + 2 seconds to the hole => 24 seconds.

Ant2 leaves 1 second behind ant1, and takes three seconds to reach the stick. it then needs to wait on both Ant0 and Ant1 to clear the stick before it can cross. Total time = 3s + 10s (waiting for ant1) + 8s (waiting for ant0) + 10s (crossing the stick) + 2s to reach the hole => 33 seconds.

so, if we were to measure the throughput of this path, it would be 
3/(15+24+33) => 0.0416 Ants per second.

lets say that we sped up leg1 to 1 second (3x faster). we end up with 
3/(13+22+31) => 0.454 Ants per second. very little increase for a 3x speed increase on one leg.

Lets say we sped up leg3 to 1 second (2x faster). we end up with 3/(12+21+30) => 0.0476 Ants per second. once again very little impact.

If we increased the speed of leg2 however, perhaps by 2x to 5 seconds, we get a very very different number 3/(7 + 11  + 17) => 0.085 Ants per second.

So an increase in either of the faster legs did very little, but doubling the rate of the slowest component effectively doubled the throughput of the path.

So do you notice that even though Leg3 has plenty of bandwidth, and a fast rate of transmission, that doesn't affect the rate at which ants reach the hole, because the rate at which ants enter Leg3 is bottlenecked by the stick, so most of the bandwidth on Leg3 is unusable. you could increase it 100-fold, and not have an iota of impact on the rate at which ants reach the hole. In this situation, the only thing you can do to change the equation at all is to increase the rate at which ants cross the stick. all else is meaningless.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand this now. When I read about transmission speeds I didn't connect it to the fact that the transmission speeds are determined by how wide the transmission path from one node to another is. And the reason that a bottleneck is created is because if one transmission path is smaller than another, than so to do the number of bits that can travel at one time.

Answer (score 2):

The end with the slowest speed will determine overall link speed because it literally cannot receive data any faster, otherwise it will result in errors.

Don't think about the time taken, think about how fast something can listen.

Put it this way: you have a person reading a book out loud, but they can speak really fast, and you have a person listening. The person listening can only comprehend at a slow rate so either the fast reader has to slow down to a speed the listener can comprehend or the listener has to keep saying "wait, can you repeat that" a lot. That determines the throughput.

You are also making a critical error in assuming that the router is holding the entire block of data to be transferred before passing it on and, while this does happen on tiny blocks of data, it is not how the overall system works.

There are two throughputs you are looking at here.  The throughput of the originator to the router and from the router to the receiver. The router only holds a small amount of the data at any given moment and will not store the entire large block before retransmitting it, thus you effectively have the slowest link in the system limiting the overall speed that the end-to-end link can work at.

Comment: "The person listening can only comprehend at a slow rate so either the fast reader has to slow down to a speed the listener can comprehend or the listener has to keep saying "wait, can you repeat that" a lot."  But is that how it actually works?  Does the receiving end have a means to say "wait, can you repeat that"?  I don't know the answer but the analogy is left with one thinking that so figured I'd ask because I am curious.  Regardless, nice analogy for giving some perspective though.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am still confused. Wouldn't the bits speed up when they hit the router? I think I understand that if the server was pushing bits out at 10 Mbps that it would take 10 seconds to get to the client if the throughput of the server to the client was the same speed.

Comment: But in the example, since the throughput from router to client is twice as fast wouldn't that change how fast the bits started moving once they reached the router? Wouldn't the formula then be ((server throughput time) + (router throughput time)) / 2? Wouldn't that cause the total throughput to be (10 seconds + 5 seconds) / 2? Therefore wouldn't it take 7.5 seconds?

Comment: Yes packets will traverse the faster link at the fastest rate possible by that link, but then there will be a delay between each packet as the router waits for an entire packet to be sent to it. Due to the fact that it is continuously passing on blocks of the data there is no apparent difference for the receiver between the fast link it has to the router and the slow link to the rest of the world beyond the router. It is essentially like an audio retransmission device, it has a tiny delay, but it still has (to some extent) to respect the speed of the data being sent to it.

Comment: @DarienSpringer  You would be essentially correct if the packet sizes were that huge, but they are normally incredibly small and so the delay in retransmission is also very small. A big piece of data gets split up into a lot of tiny packets and they flow through the network. They are limited by the slowest link because that is where they take longest to move across the link, everywhere else they move as fast as possible, but their rate of flow as a group entity is limited by how fast they can make it through the slowest link. You need to think of a continuous flow rather than a wait at point x

Comment: A chain is only as strong as it's weakest link. It doesn't matter how many or how strong the other links are, the weakest is the only one that matters. The same principle has many applications, data transfer speed being one. In the example the server is sending data at 10Mbs. The overall transfer rate cannot possibly exceed that or the last byte would be received before it was sent. Think about it.

Comment: A chain is a pretty good analogy. The chain passes through a series of cogs but due to a weakness between two of those cogs (say the chain passes through a sharp bend and risks whipping out and breaking itself) you can only run it through that link at a particular speed.  It has the effect that the whole chain link slows down.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's comments but I am still confused. Maybe I am really stuck on the wall thing but even tiny packets of bits have to go through the intermediary router. They have to be processed, queued, transmitted, and then propagated. In my example I am assuming that the delays are negligible to the point of being irrelevant. I only bring up delays because the packets will have to stop at the router and then will be propagated across the throughput from the router to the client. Because of this "wall" wouldn't the packets reach the router at a slower speed and then speed up?

Comment: Say we are still talking about the throughput speed is still 1 Mbps from server to router and 2 Mbps from server to client. Wouldn't the packets spend half of the total throughput at 1 Mbps and the other half at 2 Mbps?

Comment: A packet doesn't move at a throughput, it moves at a transmission rate for the link it is on. Throughput is a measure of the rate at which a packet travels the whole path, so a path that has two links both at 10mbps will have a throughput of 10mbps. if you upgraded one link to 100mbps, the throughput would still be 10mbps, because that is the rate at which the bits ot the packet can traverse the path.